# Additional field in array of _id's referencing another collection

Tags: mongodb

this is what I have and it works:

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
    components: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Component"
    }]  
})
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
    components: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Component",
        amount: {type: Integer}
    }]  
})
```

Is it possible in MongoDB, if not what is the best workaround?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Can you please little elaborate on your question?

Comment: @Mani it is possible to add `amount` field to model declaration but it seems not possible to populate such a field.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This schema work because of an element or filed name is provided

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
    components: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Component"
    }]  
})
```

Now you made a single mistak you want to create schema name without name in object with two different filed

Right way to create schema like this is to make other variable inside of array which contain type of filed

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
    components: [{
        id: {
             type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Component"
            },
        amount: { //If you want to make every component amount
             type: Number
        }
    }]  
})
```

Or

```
var comboSchema = new Schema({
    amount: { type: Number }, 
   //If you want to make only single amount on multiple components
    components: [{
        componentId: {
             type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Component"
            }
    }]  
})
```

But in both case you can't populate directly. You need to use aggregation for that to get data for embedded documents.

Comment: Tried your first solution. It did not work for me.`MongoDB` failed to cast object structure from your example to ObjectId to another collection. Or maybe I do something wrong? Do you have any working example of your solution by any chance please? Thank you!